# Objectify: Filter by Ref (or Key) of a Certain Kind

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Say I have these classes:

```
@Entity class MyEntity {
    @Id String id;
    @Index Ref<?> ref;
}

@Entity class Kind2 {
    ...
}
```

Can I query for all `MyEntitiy` objects where `ref` refers to any instance of `Kind2`?  If so, how?

Comment: `ofy().load().type(MyEntity.class).filter("ref", YOUR_KIND2_ORJECT);`

Comment: Sorry Shajeel, I meant where `ref` refers to **any** instance of `Kind2`.  Edited above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moshe's answer is really the right one. However, you can technically hack something that works by performing inequality queries on the key. Ie, `>= KEY('Kind2', 0)` and `<= KEY('Kind2', MAX_LONG)`. This gets significantly more complicated if your entities have parents.

I wouldn't recommend doing this unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: Tricky!  I suppose that would work for `String` ids like this: `>= KEY('Kind2', '')` and `< Key('Kind2', '\uFFFD')`.  But, as far as I can tell, that depends on undocumented behavior, yes?  Looking in the Datastore Viewer it seems keys are stored as encoded strings - I'm guessing the value returned by `KeyFactory.keyToString()`.  The details of that conversion don't appear to be documented, so we could say it is "coincidence" if the Kind comprises the most significant portion of that encoding.  Does that sound right?

Comment: I don't think it would be considered coincidence; an explicit order had to be chosen since keys are comparable objects (otherwise map/reduce would not work). Also, I don't think you can create a key with an empty string id. But if you wanted to get creative, figure out if integer ids are less than string ids, then you can compare `>= KEY('Kind2', 1)` and '`< KEY('Kind2a', 1)`. If strings are less than integers you can figure out an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible

I think something with the structure of your data maybe flawed. even when you forget the datastore, and just use `instance of` in plain java, a lot ot times it's a sign that the structure is not right.

But in any case, remember that when working with the datastore, you need to index the things you query. so if you want to query for a ref kind, figure out a way to index it. probably another property on the MyEntity is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  I'm not convinced my structure is wrong, but I suppose if that conversation is worth having it would be a topic of its own.  For now I'm just learning my options!

Answer (score 2):

I achieve it this way:

```
ofy().load().type(MyEntity.class).filter("ref =",Ref.create(new Kind2(kind2Id))).list();
```

Adding `@Index` to the ref property as you did and that's it.

It will retrieve it filtered.

Comment: This will find objects where `ref` refers to a **specific** instance of `Kind2`, yes? I was looking for where it refers to **any** instance of `Kind2`.