# Objectify Ref in a subclass

Tags: java, google-app-engine, filtering, subclass, objectify

I'm trying to get a list picking by Reference.

My classes are like:

- A License run on a Daemon,
- A License can be a LicenseCountryCondition or another subclass with a Ref (for LicenseCountryCondition, the parameter is a Ref of a Country).

**License:**

```
@Entity
@Cache
@Index
public class License {
    @Id
    Long id;
    private String name;
    private String startDate;
    private String expDate;
    private int timeStamp;
    private int status;
    Ref<Daemon> daemon;
    private boolean inactive;
}
```

**LicenseCountryCondition :**

```
@Index
@Subclass(index=true)
public class LicenseCountryCondition extends License{
    Ref<Country> country;
}
```

If I want to find a **list of the LicenseCountryCondition** working on a **specific Daemon**, I do this:

```
Daemon dae=ofy().load().type(Daemon.class).filter("name", "example").first().now();  

    List<LicenseCountryCondition>test=ofy().load().type(LicenseCountryCondition.class).filter("daemon",dae).list();
                for(LicenseCountryCondition i:test){
                    System.out.println(i.getName());
                    System.out.println(i.getDaemon().getName());
                }
```

And I got the good results.

**But**, when I try to get a **list of LicenseCountryCondition** working on a **specific Country**, it doesn't work:

```
Country ctr=ofy().load().type(Country.class).filter("name", "France").first().now();
    List<LicenseCountryCondition> test=ofy().load().type(LicenseCountryCondition.class).filter("country",ctr).list();
        for(LicenseCountryCondition i:test){
            System.out.println(i.getName());
        }
```

*Can I get this list? (I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391109/objectify-filter-by-ref-or-key-of-a-certain-kind) but it's not the same problem)*

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your query for France actually returns a real country (not null).

There's nothing obviously wrong in what you have written, but there's too much stuff going on here and too much unspecified database state for someone to be able to answer the question. The best thing to do is put together a test case that creates some entities (so the db state is known) and then demonstrates queries that you think should succeed but nevertheless fail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know why but when I tried this morning, it worked.I just saw that two of my LicenceCountryCondition were still unindexed, I think that I was working only with them yesterday

Comment: Is it possible you saved the value unindexed, then added the @Index annotation later? The annotation controls whether the property will be indexed on save; if you add the annotation, you must resave any relevant entities.

Comment: Yep I've understand my mistake now. I was thinking that because of the super, I didn't have to add an @index on my subclass, but now I realize that it was stupid because I have parameters on my subclasses what need to be indexed...
And I'm working on test data, so I re create data after understanding the problem. 
Thanks for your attention =)